# Replace contents of factor column in R dataframe

Tags: r

I need to replace the levels of a factor column in a dataframe. Using the `iris` dataset as an example, how would I replace any cells which contain `virginica` with `setosa` in the *Species* column?

I expected the following to work, but it generates a warning message and simply inserts NAs:

```
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- 'setosa'
```

Comment: Your example with `iris` just works. Can you replicate your problem in some other way? At the moment it's hard to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Works for me. Which warning message you get?

Comment: Its worked with iris when trying again. However applying the same to my dataset gives this: Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, x$Hweet == "hweet", value = c(NA_integer_,  :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated

Comment: I strongly suspect that you want to operate on the *levels* of the factor rather than on the elements themselves ... based on your previous (very similar) question, I think you might get a bit farther by asking a *slightly* longer, **reproducible**, more complete question that explains what you're trying to do ...

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I bet the problem is when you are trying to replace values with a new one, one that is not currently part of the existing factor's levels:

```
levels(iris$Species)
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Your example was bad, this works:

```
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- 'setosa'
```

This is what more likely creates the problem you were seeing with your own data:

```
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- 'new.species'
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iris$Species == "virginica", value = c(1L,  :
#   invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

It will work if you first increase your factor levels:

```
levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "new.species")
iris$Species[iris$Species == 'virginica'] <- 'new.species'
```

---

If you want to replace "species A" with "species B" you'd be better off with

```
levels(iris$Species)[match("oldspecies",levels(iris$Species))] <- "newspecies"
```

Comment: but if you want to replace species A with species B you'd be better off with `levels(iris$Species)[match("oldspecies",levels(iris$Species))] <- "newspecies"`

Answer (score 22):

For the things that you are suggesting you can just change the levels using the `levels`:

```
levels(iris$Species)[3] <- 'new'
```

Comment: Is there a one-shot way to do it on multiple columns? For example I've multiple columns with 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' values which I want to recode to '0','1'

Comment: @UD1989, just use something like: `mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, as.numeric)`

Comment: This really should be the top comment.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the function `revalue` from the package `plyr` to replace values in a factor vector.

In your example to replace the factor `virginica` by `setosa`:

```
 data(iris)
 library(plyr)
 revalue(iris$Species, c("virginica" = "setosa")) -> iris$Species
```

Comment: What if i don't have the old value ? //and don't want to fetch the old value just to use it in this methdod

Answer (score 7):

Using `dlpyr::mutate` and `forcats::fct_recode`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

iris <- iris %>%  
  mutate(Species = fct_recode(Species,
    "Virginica" = "virginica",
    "Versicolor" = "versicolor"
  )) 

iris %>% 
  count(Species)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
     Species     n
      <fctr> <int>
1     setosa    50
2 Versicolor    50
3  Virginica    50
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. This worked better:

Identify which level you want to modify: `levels(iris$Species)`

```
    "setosa" "versicolor" "virginica"
```

So, `setosa` is the first.

Then, write this:

```
     levels(iris$Species)[1] <-"new name"
```

Answer (score 3):

A more general solution that works with all the data frame at once and where you don't have to add new factors levels is:

```
data.mtx <- as.matrix(data.df)
data.mtx[which(data.mtx == "old.value.to.replace")] <- "new.value"
data.df <- as.data.frame(data.mtx)
```

A nice feature of this code is that you can assign as many values as you have in your original data frame at once, not only one `"new.value"`, and the new values can be random values. Thus you can create a complete new random data frame with the same size as the original.

Answer (score 2):

You want to replace the values in a dataset column, but you're getting an error like this:

> invalid factor level, NA generated

Try this instead:

`levels(dataframe$column)[levels(dataframe$column)=='old_value'] <- 'new_value'`

Answer (score 0):

In case you have to replace multiple values and if you don't mind "refactoring" your variable with as.factor(as.character(...)) you could try the following:

```
replace.values <- function(search, replace, x){
  stopifnot(length(search) == length(replace))
  xnew <- replace[ match(x, search) ]
  takeOld <- is.na(xnew) & !is.na(x)
  xnew[takeOld] <- x[takeOld]
  return(xnew)
}

iris$Species <- as.factor(search=c("oldValue1","oldValue2"),
                          replace=c("newValue1","newValue2"),
                          x=as.character(iris$Species))
```

Answer (score 0):

******levels(iris$Species)******

**levels(iris$Species)[3] <- 'setosa'**