# Add a numerical value to a column of factors which are already numerical

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame `z` with columns `Tracer`, `angle` and `treatment`, where angle and treatment are factors.

```
levels(z$angle)
[1] "0"  "15" "30" "45" "60" "80" "90"
```

I'd like to add the value of 150 to the numeric value in angle
e.g. if angle is 30 then it would become 180, 45 would be 195, etc.

Why doesn't this work?:

```
z$bigangle<-z$angle +150
```

I've read this post but can't really work that out as I don't already have the column bigangle: [Replace contents of factor column in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810605/replace-contents-of-factor-column-in-r-dataframe)

Any help would be much appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: Because you don't have a numeric, you have a factor. `z$bigangle = 150 + as.numeric(as.character(z$angle))` should do it. You can wrap the whole thing in `factor()` if you want it to end up as a factor at the end.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/903061

Comment: Thank you, that was suuuper fast!