# Combining 2 plots of different data (boxplot and points)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to plot two graphs ontop of each other [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192002/how-to-combine-2-plots-ggplot-into-one-plot).

**Experimental data**: I have continuous variable displaying the angle of wind on a given day in a list called `expt$iso_xs[,8]`, I then have the wind speed corresponding to that angle in `expt$iso_xs[,2]`.

```
df<-data.frame(expt$iso.xs)

head(expt$iso.xs)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5] [,6] [,7]   [,8]
 736105.4 16.62729 2.183740  7.234774 0.9791632 4.01 4.20 238.62
 736105.4 18.96705 2.489668  7.036234 0.9640366 3.82 4.00 243.14
 736105.5 20.52089 2.687636 10.355394 1.3698454 4.99 5.14 247.02
 736105.5 19.94449 2.611556 10.306912 1.3655301 4.85 5.12 249.57
 736105.5 19.43309 2.551787 11.098302 1.4646251 4.83 5.12 243.89
 736105.5 20.48259 2.689075 11.928011 1.5710530 4.89 5.09 254.23
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

**Simulation data**: I have a data.frame `z` that contains predictions for a subset of the above angles (0-90º).

```
head(z,15)
   Tracer angle treatment bigangle
  71.101     0         S      150
  71.101     0         S      150
  71.105     15         S      165
  71.105     15         S      165
  71.098     30         S      180
  71.098     45         S      195
  71.114     60         S      210
  71.114     80         S      230
  71.110     90         S      240
```

Plotting it using bigangle as factor and Tracer as :

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=z, aes(y = (3600/Tracer/93.241), x = factor(bigangle)),outlier.shape = NA,outlier.colour = NA)+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1))+
  labs(x = "Angle", y = "Normalised ACh" )+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=seq(0,360,10))+
  theme_classic()
```

looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to superimpose the boxplot ontop of the portion of red points (between 150º and 240º) but the following doesn't work:

```
ggplot() +
      geom_boxplot(data=z, aes(y = (3600/Tracer/93.241), x = factor(bigangle)),outlier.shape = NA,outlier.colour = NA)+
      geom_point(data=df, aes(y = X2/45, x = X8),color="red")+
      coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 1))+
      labs(x = "Angle", y = "Normalised ACh" )+
      scale_x_discrete(labels=seq(0,360,10))+
      theme_classic()
```

[image]

Any thoughts would be much appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: Note this is a different question to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34515961/edit but using the same data

Comment: Could you please make a minimal reproducible example with copy-pasteable data? Either use `dput()` to share data, use built-in data, or simulate data (with a random seed). I don't think the 6 rows of `expt` and 15 rows of `z` are sufficient to demo code on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your only problem is trying to specify a discrete x scale for continuous data. That and you need a `group` for your boxplot geom.

As an illustrative example:

```
mt = mtcars
mt$wt_bin = cut(mt$wt, breaks = c(1, 3, 4.5, 6))
ggplot(mt, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = wt_bin, x = wt), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

As the `geom_boxplot` help says:

> You can also use boxplots with continuous x, as long as you supply
>    a grouping variable. `cut_width` is particularly useful

The example in the help shows this code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = cut_width(carat, 0.25)))
```

You can, of course, add a `geom_point` layer (though in the `diamonds` data there are too many points for that to be a nice plot).

For your scale, don't use a discrete scale unless you have factors on the axis. You probably want `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, 10))`.

Different data sets can be used in the usual way, with the `data` argument. Continuing the previous example but using different data for the `geom_point` layer:

```
similar_to_mt = data.frame(wt = runif(100, 1, 6), mpg = rnorm(100, 20, 4))
ggplot(mt, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point(data = similar_to_mt) +
    geom_boxplot(data = mt, aes(group = wt_bin, x = wt), alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gregor. Could you for example superimpose the diamond data onto the mt plots? This is what im attempting...

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please do share data reproducibly. It would make this much faster to answer.

Comment: Superb! Thank you so much Gregor, I really appreciate it. I'm trying learn how to make data represent my own for next time. Just out of curiosity, the scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 360, 10)) argument gives an error saying: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. Do you think that's right?

Comment: I meant to ask how to change the legend as I don't get one with that plot for some reason. Even when I use: scale_color_manual("Legend Title\n",labels = c("Expt", "CFD","Loess regression"),values = c("red","black","pink"))

Comment: Since you didn't share data it's your job to convert your data to match what I simulated. In my example data, I always map the `x` aesthetic to columns of class `numeric`. Sounds like in your code you map `x` to a column of class factor. Don't do that. Convert it to `numeric`.

Comment: Convert it to `numeric` (using `as.numeric(as.factor())` as we said [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34520554/903061). The only factor I use in the example is the column I map to `group`, which determines which points go into which boxplot.

Comment: As for the legend, that's a new question (though if you look around, it's probably a duplicate).

Comment: With respect to the part about factors...I wanted to make a grouped boxplot with different factors so is this not the way to do it?

Comment: Just **don't use `aes(x = factor_column)`**. If you need to ask another question, do so using a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).