# R how to keep top levels and change all the other levels

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm not an expert in R...

In my training data, there is a field called `Source` which has 30 levels, I just want to keep the top 2 levels since they are the majority, and need to change all the other 28 levels in to 'Other'. In this way, it will be easier for me to apply One-Hot Encoding later.

I have checked solutions here:[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810605/replace-contents-of-factor-column-in-r-dataframe) and [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824173/replace-a-value-in-a-data-frame-based-on-a-conditional-if-statement-in-r)

And I still got stucked...

Here are the major solutions I tried:

`train` is the original training data, `x_train` is just a copy. `Source` is a factor variable.
**The top 2 levels are 'S122' which is level1, and 'S133' which is level8**

**Try 1**

Here I'm using `which`, so that I don't need to convert factor into character first. In fact, before using `which`, I tried to convert factor into character. The results are the same, didn't work.... After running the code here, nothing changed but just added 1 more level called 'Other'...

```
x_train <- train
levels(x_train$Source) <- c(levels(x_train$Source), "Other")
x_train$Source[which((x_train$Source != 'S122') && (x_train$Source != 'S133'))] <- 'Other'
str(x_train$Source)
```

Meanwhile, in this case, I am not using methods like `revalue()`because there are 28 levels need to be changed, I don't want to write 28 values in a method....

**Try 2**

Then, I changed to a very simply way, iteration... I tried `while` loop too, didn't work either.

```
x_train <- train
for (i in 1:30) {
  if (i == 1 || i == 8) {
    next
  }
  levels(x_train$Source)[i] <- 'Other'
}
```

After using this method, not all the 28 levels will be changed, and I have realized, while the values of those levels have been changed, the length of the total levels is changing too and the index will be changed. That's why I changed to `while` loop but still it didn't work....

**Therefore, is there any way for me to just keep the top 2 levels and change all the other levels into 'Other'?**

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so, please share, if not, please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem in a simply way but looks silly, I will share that after work today~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a reproducible example, since you do not provide the data but assuming that your factor is part of train, you can use.

```
levels(train$source) <-c("S122", "S133", rep("Other",3))
```

For example, imagine the titanic data.

```
titanic <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
head(titanic)
  Class    Sex   Age Survived value
1   1st   Male Child       No     0
2   2nd   Male Child       No     0
3   3rd   Male Child       No    35
4  Crew   Male Child       No     0
5   1st Female Child       No     0
6   2nd Female Child       No     0
```

Now, suppose that I wanted to relabel the factors such that the highest two factors are in a class, and the other factors are in another class. I do not need any for loops. I just write

```
 levels(titanic$Class) <-c("High", "High", "Low", "Low")
```

Now when I look at the levels I get

```
titanic
   Class    Sex   Age Survived value
1   High   Male Child       No     0
2   High   Male Child       No     0
3    Low   Male Child       No    35
4    Low   Male Child       No     0
5   High Female Child       No     0
6   High Female Child       No     0
```

Comment: This is a good inspiration. While I will choose this as the solution, 1 thing need to correct, the `levels(train$source) <-c("S122",  rep("Other",6), "S133", rep("Other",22))`. Because in my case, "S133" is level 8 but it has top 2 counts, "S122" is level 1 and it has top 1 counts, I need to change those levels between "S122" and "S133" in to "Other", and change those after S133 into "Other" too.

Comment: Yes, that looks right. Next time, you could help people who want to help you by sharing a [minimal dataset which resembles your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That way, I would know the order of the levels of your factors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem, but the solution is not very intelligent. So, **if there will be better solution for this problem, feel free to post it here**.

Let's recall the major part I mentioned in the question:

`x_train` is the copy of `train`.

x_train$Source has 30 levels, **level1** is 'S122' and **level8** is 'S133', I just want to keep these 2 levels and set the other 28 levels as 'Other'.

If this description is still not clear to you, here's the example:

**Origional x_train$Source 30 levels**

S122, S123, S124.., S133, S134,....

**Final x_train$Source levels**

S122, Other, S133

My question was how to get the final result, how to change 30 levels into 3 levels

Here's the solution:

```
x_train <- train
summary(x_train$Source)
levels(x_train$Source)[2] <- 'Other'
for (i in 3:7) {
  levels(x_train$Source)[3] <- 'Other'
}
summary(x_train$Source)
for (j in 1:22) {
  levels(x_train$Source)[4] <- 'Other'
}
summary(x_train$Source)
```

As you can see, in the code, there is hard coding part, which is not good.

**So, if there are better solution, very welcome to post it here!**

Comment: Cherry, please see my edits to this question, clarifying why it would be best to use my solution.

Comment: Hi Shayaa, thank you very much for the patience to modify your solution, now I can understand what do you mean. Just added a comment under your solution to let it fit for my case. But your solution is a good inspiration and it's a good learning experience for me. Thank you very much!