# How do i change a String value to an integer value in R-studio

Tags: r

So i have this csv data which have a couple of String variable, I wanted to change it to integer how can I do that? the data is >200000 i want to change it to 200000

Comment: try `as.numeric("200000")`

Comment: Hi! See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810605/replace-contents-of-factor-column-in-r-dataframe

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Remove punctuation, then convert to numeric:

```
x = c(1, 2, ">200")
as.numeric(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x))
# [1] 1 2 200
```

Or, for a data in a column:

```
data$x = as.numeric(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", data$x))
```

Answer (score -1):

Since i have noting to go on, I will give a general solution.

Data:

```
col <- sample(1:100, 5, replace=FALSE)
col <- c(col, ">200000")
df <- as.data.frame(col, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Solution 1:

```
df$col[df$col == ">200000"] <- "200000"
df$col <- as.integer(df$col)
```

Solution 2:

```
df$col <- replace(df$col, df$col == ">200000", "200000")
df$col <- as.integer(df$col)
```

Comment: I think `as.numeric` makes no sense in the second code. The output is still character. I use `x <- c(">200", "100", "100")` for test.

Comment: I see that now.