# Find and Replace Based on A Lookup Table in R and Leave Unmatched Ones As Is

Tags: r

I have gone through many threads about it but they don't seem to have the solution I really need. Just wanted to comment on the differences of my question from suggested posts:

- [Replace contents of factor column in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810605/replace-contents-of-factor-column-in-r-dataframe) is different from what I was asking. My real dataset and lookup table were a lot bigger so replace them one by one in the code was really not an option.
- [Replace values in a dataframe based on lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636315/replace-values-in-a-dataframe-based-on-lookup-table) this is also different since it has all combination there without unmatched entries so it's also different.

I have two data frames:

```
> main <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("A","B","C","C","D","E","A")))
> main
V1
 A
 B
 C
 C
 D
 E
 A

> lookup <- data.frame(V1=c("A","B","C"),V2=c("aa","bb","cc"))
> lookup
V1 V2
 A aa
 B bb
 C cc
```

What I need is to use `lookup` to update `main` but leave the unmatched ones as is. Many of the answers involved using `match` but it created an `NA` for unmatched levels. For example, one of the solution was:

```
> main$V1=lookup[match(main$V1,lookup$V1),"V2"]
> main
   V1
   aa
   bb
   cc
   cc
 <NA>
 <NA>
   aa
```

The desired outcome is to leave the unmatched ones unchanged:

```
V1
aa 
bb
cc
cc
 D
 E
aa
```

That was an example and my real datasets were a lot bigger so replace them one by one was really not an option. Any help or pointer will be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195435/680068) in linked post. This should work: `library(tidyverse); main %>% mutate(V1 = fct_recode(V1,"aa" = "A","bb" = "B","cc" = "C"))`

Comment: Thanks, but my actual datasets were a lot bigger so replace them one by one was really not an option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `match` output to conditionally change values.

```
inds <- match(main$V1, lookup$V1)
main$V1[!is.na(inds)] <- lookup$V2[na.omit(inds)]
main

#  V1
#1 aa
#2 bb
#3 cc
#4 cc
#5  D
#6  E
#7 aa
```

---

You can also use the join approach :

```
library(dplyr)
main %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = 'V1') %>%
  transmute(V1 = coalesce(V2, V1))
```

Comment: Thanks much. So it seems like your solution will work if the variable is ```character``` but it does not work for ```factor```. Is there anyway to do it without changing the data format?

Comment: For `factors` you need to include all its levels in the column. Run `levels(main$V1) <- union(levels(main$V1), levels(lookup$V2))` and then run the above answer.